# Getting RuntimeError: command not found: initdb for testing.postgresql.Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing

I have following code.

```
import testing.postgresql
sql = testing.postgresql.Postgresql(copy_data_from=r"path_to_my_sql_file.sql")
```

I want to create dummy data for unit testing
but getting this error

```
raise RuntimeError("command not found: %s" % name)
RuntimeError: command not found: initdb
```

FYI: I am trying this for database mocking for unit testing
If there are better ways to do it, please share, Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and somehow it seems I was missing postgresql, even thought it used work previously. :)
If on mac you can use brew:

```
brew install postgresql
```